# Frequency of fluctuations in power in an input power design circuit

Tags: power, dc

I am thinking about the following power design circuit in section 6.1 : http://www.arndaleboard.org/wiki/downloads/supports/BaseBoard_Specification_Arndale_Ver1_0.pdf

Is it possible to calculate how fast the fluctuations in power might be at most from this ? If I measure samples of the input current with 1ms intervals, would this be sufficient to get a fair precision of variations over time, or would the fluctuations that appear when the load varies "destroy" my readings ?

EDIT : Sorry, I meant to say that I measure the input current, not voltage! (I measure the voltage drop across a shunt resistor coupled in series with the input. I am trying to measure the board's power and energy consumption with low accuracy)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little ambiguous. What does "power fluctuation" mean here?

Yes, you can calculate the frequency response of the two sections; the 5V input is a capacitor filtered part which turns into an RC filter (with the ESR of the capacitors.) The post-regulator part (3.3V?) is an LC filter. Knowing the values of the components, you can calculate the frequency response of the system. Additionally, you need to model the voltage regulator in that circuit, if you worry about the voltage out of that system. (Note that the regulator may introduce ringing in response to steps in power demand.)

But what does "power fluctuation" mean? The board may draw varying amounts of power with different workloads. This may affect the voltage of the input power supply if the source impedance is not zero. Exactly how quickly the power will vary depends both on the source impedance of your power supply, and the filtering section of the board power.

So, depending on the fluctuations in power demand of the board, you can characterize the system. If the board can go from demanding 1 mA, to demanding 10 A, in one microsecond, then that's a megahertz-range signal, and a millisecond sample will not be sufficient to show the ringing involved. In general, you're going to have a much better time just measuring the ringing as a result of steps in power demand using an oscilloscope, rather than trying to calculate it, as the ESR of capacitors and the response of the voltage regulator will not be very accurately characterized values.

Comment: Thank you for your response. By "power fluctuation" I was thinking about the fluctuation in power demand the board has. I have no idea how fast the board can do this. It has a 1.7GHz cpu, so I hope its not able to fluctuate that fast :) I use a multimeter for sampling, and I was wondering if the frequency of variations in power demand could be determined wrt to that circuit (Smoothing). If only considering the power demand with a perfect power supply, could it be possible to calculate the fluctuations somehow ? (I'm an electricity noob) Or do I have to look at something else than that circuit?

Comment: By the way, I am measuring the input current, not voltage. Sorry.

Comment: With a perfect power supply, there will be no voltage fluctuation (except for wire and component losses,) because it will be able to provide whatever current is needed.

The capacitors help filter the maximum slew rate of transients due to power demand. The regulator does the same -- and, in fact, may significantly help filter demand on the right side from supply on the left side; values of 60-80 dB is not uncommon. You really need an oscilloscope to answer the question for real for the actual circuit, though.